# How do I identify if it's system or not and also if the force is internal or external?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image: Newton's laws problem]

As you can see, there are two problems related to system. First one is a closed or isolated system and second one is not a closed system. So how do I know if the given set of bodies is a system or not? And what does it mean by internal force?

Answer (score 1):

A closed or isolated system is one where there are no interactions with anything that is external to that system. Whether something is internal or external completely depends on how we define the system. For example, if we have three particles interacting with each other and nothing else, then defining just two of our particles as our system would not give us an isolated system, but the entire three-particle system would be isolated. Of course, truly isolated systems can never exist, but it is still a useful approximation to use in many situations.

This leads to internal forces. If a force is between two objects in our system (however we define it) then it is an internal force. If a force is present between something (or some things) in the system and something not in the system, then it is an external force acting on the system. For example, if I drop a ball and define my system to just be the ball, then gravity is an external force. However, if I define my system to be the ball and the Earth, then gravity between the ball and Earth is an internal force.

So as you can see, these things really come down to just how we define our system, which is completely up to us.